# Difference between Different Notations of 2-d Vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I am playing around with vectors and stumbled upon different types of 2-d vectors.Can someone please point out key differences between these vector declarations.

Which of them are actually 2-d vector -

```
//c++ format
//All libraries preincluded
 1) std::vector <int,int> v1;
 2) std::vector <pair<int,int>> v2;
 3) std::vector <int> v(10);
 4) struct node{
       int a,b;
     }
     std::vector<node> v4;
 5) std::vector< vector<int> > v5;
```

Comment: They're all technically "2D". It all depends on your needs.

Comment: The first one isn't even legal syntax as far as I am aware.

Comment: Looks like you're not really playing around when you're using `int` as an allocator.

Comment: Does the code compile?The second and fifth one misses the std:: namespace identifier.

Comment: @GiladNaaman what do you mean with "They're all technically "2D"" ? These are all quite different data structures ranging from a simple vector (that I would not call 2D at all) to a vector of vectors (which no sane coder would normally use for a simple 2d structure)

Comment: @tobi303 What I mean is that there is no "One true 2D vector blessed upon by the gods". Yeah, options 1, 3, and 5 are not even remotely close to what he wants.

Comment: 1 and 3 I'll give you, @GiladNaaman , but fix a syntax glitch and 5 comes closest.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm not sure about it. 5 can give you a non-rectangular vector. I mean, I assumed that by a 2D vector he meant something that is akin to a matrix, but a vector of vectors can have different size rows / columns.

Comment: Comes closest, but still has bad behaviour. 5 also gives you horrid caching. Given what OP seems to want, `std::vector <int[2]>` is probably the easiest to deal with.

Comment: @orbitcowbot Sir,That was just the declaration part.I've included all prerequisites in my code.Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `std::vector<int,int> v1`

This is illegal syntax, a `std::vector` holds only a single type of data - the second template argument can be used for a custom allocator object.

> `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> v2`

This declares a `std::vector` which holds objects of type `std::pair<int,int>` such that each element of the vector holds two integers in a pair construct.

> `std::vector<int> v(10)`

Constructs a `std::vector` of `int` types with 10 default-inserted instances of `int`.

> `std::vector<node> v4`

Declares a `std::vector` holding objects of type `node` where `node` is defined in your question. Each node has two public `int` fields so acts in a similar way to `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>`.

> `std::vector< std::vector<int> > v5`

This declares a `std::vector` of `std::vector<int>` objects such that `v5` is a "2d vector" (I use that term loosely, technically it's not really 2d) - i.e. each element of `v5` contains a `std::vector<int>` object.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is none of the above.

There is no such thing as a 2D `vector`. All `vectors` are 1D, but may contain objects that lend the appearance of additional dimensions.

Consider option 5. This is a `vector` which contains other `vector`s and certainly can look 2D when used. The outer `vector` supplies one dimension and the contained `vector`s supply the other. But it isn't a 2D `vector`. It is a `vector` of `vectors`.

```
std::vector <int,int> v1;
```

Invalid syntax. This specifies the allocator to be of type `int` and probably results in several pages of bizarro error messages.

```
std::vector <pair<int,int>> v2;
```

Will provide an N x 2 matrix, but accessing the pairs is cumbersome `v2[n].first`? Yuck.

```
std::vector <int> v(10);
```

This is a 1D vector, but it could be treated as a 5x2 matrix if you are willing to do the math yourself: `v[row*2+column]`

```
struct node{
   int a,b;
 }
 std::vector<node> v4;
```

Almost identical to option 2. `v4[n].a` is not bad, but could be better.

```
std::vector< vector<int> > v5;
```

Covered above. This has merit, but allows non-rectangular shape and has horrible cache performance because each of the many `vector`s is it's own beast with it's own memory and that memory may be scattered throughout storage. Read up on spatial locality to see why this is bad.

I pitch option 6

```
std::vector<int[2]> v6;
```

This is all contiguous storage and looks like an N x 2 matrix: `v6[row][column]`.

Answer (score -1):

1. illegal?
2. N by 2 vectors
3. 1D vector (reserve space for 10 elements)
4. N by 2 vectors
5. vector of vectors. Can be N by M, or even in irregular shape.

2) 4) 5) access cells differently. Assume that you want to access cell at row x, column y:

- 2) y==0: v2[x].first; y==1 v2[x].second
- 4) y==0: v4[x].a; y==1 v4[x].b
- 5) v5[x][y]

Comment: 5 is not N by N vectors. It is a vector of vectors, each of them being allowed to have a different size.

Comment: @tobi303, I use the term loosely, but you're right.